# minimize number of Django Querysets to create json.dumps

Tags: django, json, django-queryset

First of all, thank you for your time and help :)

I created the model below and for sometime have been happily coding with Scenario 1 (Scenarios also below).

Now I started to use charts and need to access data in the form of Scenario 2. Scenario 2 works – with the added value that I have the time to make a sandwich while waiting for the results. I know this is caused by the fact that I’m hitting the database four times, so I probably have created the most inefficient piece of code in the history of code, but I have failed to make it work otherwise.

I would really appreciate your help understanding how to achieve the desired result without offending every single principle that Django stands for.

Thank you again!

```
Model:

    class People_stats(models.Model):
    people_stats = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)        
    con_basmat = models.IntegerField(null=True, max_length=6) 
    con_cgoods = models.IntegerField(null=True, max_length=6) 
    con_cserv = models.IntegerField(null=True, max_length=6)                 


   SCENARIO 1 - when iterating in template 

     Views:

        people = ['Name', 'Benchmark1', 'Benchmark2', 'Benchmark3']
        people_names = [form.cleaned_data[p] for p in people]            

        profiles =  [People_stats.objects.filter(name__in=people_names)] 

     Template: 

        {% for p in profiles %}
          {%for d in p %}              
            <ul>
              <li>{{d.con_basmat}}</li>
              <li>{{d.con_cgoods}}</li>
              <li>{{d.con_cserv}}</li>                        
            </ul> 
          {%endfor%} 
        {% endfor %}       


    #Scenario 2 - when I need to access model fields and create a json.dump  

      Views:

        N = form.cleaned_data['Name']
        B1 = form.cleaned_data['Benchmark1']
        B2 = form.cleaned_data['Benchmark2']
        B3 = form.cleaned_data['Benchmark3']

        dir_prof1 =  People_stats.objects.filter(name__exact=N)
        dir_prof2 =  People_stats.objects.filter(name__exact=B1)
        dir_prof3 =  People_stats.objects.filter(name__exact=B2)
        dir_prof4 =  People_stats.objects.filter(name__exact=B3)

        for d in dir_prof1:               
          con_ind1 = ['Basic Materials', d.con_basmat],['Consumer Goods', d.con_cgoods],['Consumer Services',d.con_cserv]

        for d in dir_prof2:               
          con_ind2 = ['Basic Materials', d.con_basmat],['Consumer Goods', d.con_cgoods],['Consumer Services',d.con_cserv]

        for d in dir_prof3:               
          con_ind3 = ['Basic Materials', d.con_basmat],['Consumer Goods', d.con_cgoods],['Consumer Services',d.con_cserv]

        for d in dir_prof4:               
          con_ind4 = ['Basic Materials', d.con_basmat],['Consumer Goods', d.con_cgoods],['Consumer Services',d.con_cserv]

        con_ind_dmp1 = json.dumps(con_ind1, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

        con_ind_dmp2 = json.dumps(con_ind2, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

        con_ind_dmp3 = json.dumps(con_ind3, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

        con_ind_dmp4 = json.dumps(con_ind4, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

      Template: 
         I don't think we need to make it that far to realize that this is not the way to go :(
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

for d in dir_prof1:
  con_ind1 = {'Basic Materials': d.con_basmat, 'Consumer Goods': d.con_cgoods, 'Consumer Services': d.con_cserv}

for d in dir_prof2:
  con_ind2 = {'Basic Materials': d.con_basmat, 'Consumer Goods': d.con_cgoods, 'Consumer Services',d.con_cserv}

for d in dir_prof3:
  con_ind3 = {'Basic Materials': d.con_basmat, 'Consumer Goods': d.con_cgoods , 'Consumer Services': d.con_cserv}

for d in dir_prof4:
  con_ind4 = {'Basic Materials': d.con_basmat, 'Consumer Goods': d.con_cgoods, 'Consumer Services': d.con_cserv}

con_ind_dmp1 = json.dumps(con_ind1)

con_ind_dmp2 = json.dumps(con_ind2)

con_ind_dmp3 = json.dumps(con_ind3)

con_ind_dmp4 = json.dumps(con_ind4)

Comment: Thank you for your answer - its cleaner code, however my main concern is that hitting the database four times results in very slow performance, so the main problem I need to resolve is not having to generate:
  dir_prof1 =  People_stats.objects.filter(name__exact=N)
        dir_prof2 =  People_stats.objects.filter(name__exact=B1)
        dir_prof3 =  People_stats.objects.filter(name__exact=B2)
        dir_prof4 =  People_stats.objects.filter(name__exact=B3) 
essentially 4 querysets.